# Historical CPU Utilization by Service Name In RHEL 6.2

Tags: linux, redhat, central-processing-unit, utilization

I need to implement historical CPU Utilization by service name in Linux Red Hat 6.2.

Is there any software or command which can provide such details ?

Comment: How much history do you need?

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at [atop](http://www.atoptool.nl/) and [psacct](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-log-user-activity-using-process-accounting.html).

Also, I have to ask if you really mean [Red Hat 6.2 or RHEL 6.2](http://linuxmafia.com/faq/RedHat/releases.html).

Comment: Its Red hat 6.2 and both commands you have mentioned are unrecognized by OS.

Comment: Ya, you need to install them first :)